# AJAX without jQuery is not sending POST data to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I've been trying to get an ajax alert layer to work with a POST method for several days and I can't come up with a reason for it not working. I use the same basic code to send form data through ajax with POST on other admin pages without trouble but when I try to send data that does not come from a form nothing gets to the server in $_POST.

Here's the flow of the code...

I use variables on a page like these:

```
$alertLayer = 1;
$autoCloseAlertLayer = 1;
$addAlertLayerCloseButton = 1;
$alertLayerMessage = $alertLayerMessage . '<h1>Test</h1><p>3rd test of the alert layer module.</p>';
$redirect = 0;
$redirectTo = 0;
```

and I include a script that calls a function at the bottom of the page like this:

```
if ($alertLayer == true)
{   
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' id='alertLayerScript'>Lib.ajaxAlertFunction('/Modules/AlertLayer', $autoCloseAlertLayer, $addAlertLayerCloseButton, '$alertLayerMessage', $redirect, '$redirectTo');</script>";
}
```

Here's the script that gets called:

```
Lib.ajaxAlertFunction = function (senturl, autoClose, closeButton, message, redirect, redirectTo)
{   
var ajaxRequest;

try
{
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
    try
    {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObjext("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObjext("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert ("Your browser can't handle the truth!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if (!senturl)
{
    return false;
}
else
{

    // var data = "autoClose=" + encodeURIComponent(autoClose) + "&closeButton=" + encodeURIComponent(closeButton) + "&message=" + encodeURIComponent(message) + "&redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(redirect) + "&redirectTo=" + encodeURIComponent(redirectTo);
    // var data = encodeURIComponent("autoClose=" + autoClose + "&closeButton=" + closeButton + "&message=" + message + "&redirect=" + redirect + "&redirectTo=" + redirectTo);
    var data = "autoClose=" + autoClose + "&closeButton=" + closeButton + "&message=" + message + "&redirect=" + redirect + "&redirectTo=" + redirectTo;
}

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById('outerFrame').innerHTML += ajaxRequest.responseText;

        newAlertLayer = document.getElementById('alertLayer');
        var arr = newAlertLayer.getElementsByTagName('script')
        for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
        {
            eval(arr[n].innerHTML)
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open('POST', senturl, true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajaxRequest.send(data);
}
```

NOTE: I have no problem sending this data with a 'GET' method but then a long message gets cut off. I have also tried to set up the 'data' variable in several different methods that I've searched over the past 3 days with no success.

The code that expects $_POST data goes as follows:

```
<?php
$ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
<div id="alertLayer">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php $ROOT ?>/Modules/AlertLayer/alertLayer.css">
<script src="/Modules/AlertLayer/alertLayer.js"></script>
<div id="alertBlock">
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<p>" . $key . " = " . $value . "</p>";
}
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<p>" . $key . " = " . $value . "</p>";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

What am I missing? What is different from sending form data with POST and sending variables concatenated the same way?
Again, GET is working when I add the data to the url string but not sufficient, POST = no data at all received on the other end of the ajaxRequest but the rest of the request returns exactly what is expected. The $_POST data missing from the server request is currently the only problem that I cannot solve with this code.

It's looking like the request is not being sent properly but I'm unable to determine the reason. Here's a screenshot of what NETWORK tab in chrome:

Comment: Try removing the `encodeURIComponent` from the data.... Like you said, it gets truncacted - without it seems fine.

Comment: I just edited the above code to show what I had originally started with before trying things like encodeURIComponent and others. Using just the string as it is concatenated together was where my problem started and I guess why I had no problem using GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the ajaxRequest the url MUST have a "/" at the end of the url (if you're not specifying an /index.php file for example).

I was using '/Modules/AlertLayer' and changing to '/Modules/AlertLayer/' has fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Problem was a redirection (301) issued by nginx due to a missing slash at the end of the URL. This caused the POST request to be changed to GET.

Technical Details: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

---

Old approach that started the discussion:

*Your Problem seems to be the `encodeURIComponent()` function that you're wrapping around the whole data string. This replaces the & signs with `&amp;` values. If you debug this in the browsers developer console you'll see that it is not recognized as form data in the request. You should only escape the variables you're filling in.*

*Btw: This should also be problematic when you use GET.*

Comment: Thanks, I should have covered more of my previous work though. Using encodeURICompenent() was one of my last efforts to try and make it work. I started with a string as is now edited and shown in the code above. If everything else looks to be ok, what kinds of things/conditions (Server settings etc.) should I look at that might be causing this issue?

Comment: I get this back when I alert(data)
autoClose=1&closeButton=1&message=<h1>Test</h1><p>3rd test of the alert layer module.</p>&redirect=0&redirectTo=0
and I use this line instead when sending a GET (and it works).
ajaxRequest.open("GET", senturl + "?" + data, true);

Comment: Did you escape the values that you have in the variables with encodeURIComponent()? Not the whole string. But every single Variable you get put into your function.

Comment: Just added a commented line with what I think you're describing that I've tested and has failed.

Comment: I tried the example of @ramraider and it doesn't seem to matter if you encode the values or not. So I was wrong there. Have you checked in the browser console how the request looks like? (In Chrome this is in the "Network"-Tab of the Developer Tools.) From this you could see if the problem is the request or your server.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, in the Network tab it shows the XHR request URL looks as it should ending with /Modules/AlertLayer/ and nothing after it but oddly it shows the request method was GET even though the code is using ajaxRequest.open('POST', senturl, true); what else should I be looking for here?

Comment: should the url have a data string after the directory when it is using the POST method? Because there's nothing there like you'd see in a GET request.

Comment: As Method you should see POST. If you click on the file in the list you should see the send headers. Below this there should be part called "Form Data" which should contain the values sent.

Comment: Ok, i added a link to an image in the original post up there. It shows what I see when I refresh the page that calls the request. Not at all what I'd expect and I have no idea where to start looking for what would cause this to be so different here from what you've tested.

Comment: Thank you! Your continued effort to help me has lead me to the problem. I knew it would be something simple and it was. The URL must have an ending "/" and I was using '/Modules/AlertLayer' without the ending backslash as it has always worked in everything else I've done. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, I think I found your problem. You're accessing the folder '/Modules/AlertLayer'. But your nginx ist returning '301 Moved Permanently' and is redirecting to '/Modules/AlertLayer/'. This also changes the the request type from POST to GET. For explanation see this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less what I tried and it was sending data via POST.

```
    window.onload=function(){
        Lib.ajaxAlertFunction( '/test/target.php', 0, 0, 'Fantastic - data is being sent via POST! Amazeballs!', 0, 0 );
    };



    var Lib={}; /* Because I don't have the rest of `Lib` at my disposal */
    Lib.ajaxAlertFunction = function ( senturl, autoClose, closeButton, message, redirect, redirectTo ) {   
        var ajax;/* renamed only for brevity */
        try {
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObjext("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajax = new ActiveXObjext("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert ("Your browser can't handle the truth!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( !senturl ) return false;
        else {
            var data =  "autoClose=" + autoClose + "&closeButton=" + closeButton + "&message=" + message + "&redirect=" + redirect + "&redirectTo=" + redirectTo;
        }


        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if( ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200 ) {
                /*
                document.getElementById('outerFrame').innerHTML += ajax.responseText;
                newAlertLayer = document.getElementById('alertLayer');
                var arr = newAlertLayer.getElementsByTagName('script')
                for ( var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++ ) {
                    eval( arr[n].innerHTML );
                }
                */

                console.log( ajax.responseText );
            }
        }
        ajax.open( 'POST', senturl, true );
        ajax.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
        ajax.send( data );
    }
```

For the sake of the test, `/test/target.php` was simply:

```
<?php
    exit( print_r($_POST,true) );
?>
```

and the response:

```
Array
(
    [autoClose] => 0
    [closeButton] => 0
    [message] => Fantastic - data is being sent via POST! Amazeballs!
    [redirect] => 0
    [redirectTo] => 0
)
```

If it helps any, here is a basic ajax function I use in tests, perhaps something in there might be of use?

```
        function _ajax( url, options ){
            var factories=[
                function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
                function() { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); },
                function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); },
                function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0'); },
                function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0'); },
                function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0'); },
                function() { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
            ];
            /* Try each factory until we have a winner */
            for( var i=0; i < factories.length; i++ ) {
                try { var req = factories[ i ](); if( req!=null ) { break; } }
                catch( err ) { continue; }
            };

            var method=options.hasOwnProperty('method') ? options.method.toUpperCase() : 'POST';
            var callback=options.hasOwnProperty('callback') ? options.callback :false;

            if( !callback ){
                alert( 'No callback function assigned - a callback is required to handle the response data' );
                return false;
            }

            var headers={
                'Accept': "text/html, application/xml, application/json, text/javascript, "+"*"+"/"+"*"+"; charset=utf-8",
                'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            };

            /* The main parameters of the request */
            var params=[];
            if( options.hasOwnProperty('params') && typeof( options.params )=='object' ){
                for( var n in options.params ) params.push( n + '=' + options.params[n] );
            }

            /* Additional arguments that can be passed to the callback function */
            var args=options.hasOwnProperty('args') ? options.args : options;

            /* Assign callback to handle response */
            req.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if( req.readyState==4 ) {
                   if( req.status==200 ) options.callback.call( this, req.response, args );
                   else console.warn( 'Error: '+req.status+' status code returned' );
                }
            }

            /* Execute the request according to desired method */
            switch( method ){
                case 'POST':
                    req.open( method, url, true );
                    for( header in headers ) req.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );
                    req.send( params.join('&') );
                break;
                case 'GET':
                    req.open( method, url+'?'+params.join('&'), true );
                    for( header in headers ) req.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );
                    req.send( null );
                break;  
            }
        }



/* to use */
_ajax.call( this, '/test/target.php',{ callback:console.info, method:'post',params:{'field':'value','field2':'value2'} } );
```

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, I'll use your examples to try and figure this out but if you've taken my code and proven it works then I think I'm overlooking a problem somewhere else but I have no idea how to track it down.

Comment: use `console.log` throughout at various points where you think errors might creep in and watch the output...